# How do I label the group for consecutive pattern in R?

Tags: r, label

I'm trying to label for each group. This is the dataset.

```
   group
1    p01
2    p01
3    p01
4    p01
5    p02
6    p01
7    p01
8    p01
9    p02
10   p02
11   p01
12   p01
```

> structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L,  1L,
>   2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("p01", "p02"), class = "factor")), class =
>   "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
>   -12L))

This is expected table. In case of p01, the expected column is 1 from 1-4, and then 2 from 6-8, 3 from 11-12 for considering consecutive patterns.

```
   group new_group
1    p01         1
2    p01         1
3    p01         1
4    p01         1
5    p02         1
6    p01         2
7    p01         2
8    p01         2
9    p02         2
10   p02         2
11   p01         3
12   p01         3
```

How do I make that using dplyr in r?

Comment: `rle` may be useful here.

Comment: I will consider that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possibility:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df <- structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("p01", "p02"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))

df %>%
  mutate(new_group = with(rle(as.integer(group)), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  transmute(new_group = as.integer(as.factor(new_group))) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 12 x 2
#>    group new_group
#>    <fct>     <int>
#>  1 p01           1
#>  2 p01           1
#>  3 p01           1
#>  4 p01           1
#>  5 p02           1
#>  6 p01           2
#>  7 p01           2
#>  8 p01           2
#>  9 p02           2
#> 10 p02           2
#> 11 p01           3
#> 12 p01           3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Is this it?

```r
x %>%
  mutate(new_group = cumsum(group == "p01" & lag(group != "p01", default = TRUE)))
#    group new_group
# 1    p01         1
# 2    p01         1
# 3    p01         1
# 4    p01         1
# 5    p02         1
# 6    p01         2
# 7    p01         2
# 8    p01         2
# 9    p02         2
# 10   p02         2
# 11   p01         3
# 12   p01         3
```

Comment: Based on the sample data you provided and no explanation of any new-grouping logic, I think I did pretty well reproducing your expected output. Please do two things: (1) provide a more-variable data sample; and (2) discuss the logic that must be considered when doing this.

Comment: I'm sorry to you and I will do that. I'm really sorry to you.

Comment: No need for an apology, really, just try to improve the MWE to better represent your needs.

Answer (score 2):

We could create a column with `row_number()` and for each `group` increment the counter whenever the difference of row is greater than 1.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(new_group = cumsum(row - lag(row, default = first(row)) > 1) + 1) %>%
  select(-row)

#   group new_group
#   <fct>     <dbl>
# 1 p01           1
# 2 p01           1
# 3 p01           1
# 4 p01           1
# 5 p02           1
# 6 p01           2
# 7 p01           2
# 8 p01           2
# 9 p02           2
#10 p02           2
#11 p01           3
#12 p01           3
```

Or a little shorter using `diff`

```
df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(new_group = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(row) > 1))) %>%
  select(-row)
```